# Importing Files for SFTP into Lists

Tags: marketing-cloud, list, data-import-wizard

I am trying to import files from my SFTP into a list. These files were exported from Marketing Cloud. When I run the wizard, I get an error message saying the file cannot be found, even though I have copied and pasted the file name from the FTP.

Here is the error message:

[image: List Upload Error]

I will appreciate any direction on this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot import an exported file as it is in the wrong directory of the Enhanced FTP. You need to move it from the Export directory to the Import directory.

> Files you import must reside in the IMPORT folder so the system can find them. The system puts your data extracts in the EXPORT folder. The system puts your reports in the REPORTS folder. [(Source: Marketing Cloud Documentation - Enhanced FTP Guide)](http://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/resources/enhanced_ftp_guide/)

Comment: If you want a workaround to use the Export folder directly, you can actually set the Export Directory as a new 'File Location' within the Admin settings of your account. Admin --> Data Management --> File Management --> Create, and set the Location Type as 'Relative Location under FTP Site', and list 'Export' as the Relative Folder Path. When creating an Import interaction you can then use that folder - may come in handy at some point.